# Unable to read a log file and loading to db java

Tags: java, jpa

I have a log file with data as such

```
2017-01-01 00:00:11.763|192.168.234.82|"GET / HTTP/1.1"|200|"swcd (unknown version) CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/15.6.0"

2017-01-01 00:00:21.164|192.168.234.82|"GET / HTTP/1.1"|200|"swcd (unknown version) CFNetwork/808.2.16 Darwin/15.6.0"
```

I have over 20 lines i want to read each line and first get a line and split by pipe |

so my idea was first to create a simple bean that can take the seperated data in their setter methods so i can save them in db 
But i have not bean able to accurately read the first line

From my code you could get the idea of what i want to do.

```
      public static LogBean readFile() throws IOException {

                Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("/resources/access.txt"));

                LogBean logBean = new LogBean();

                String string =  read.nextLine();
                Scanner readFileByLine = new Scanner(string);

                while (readFileByLine.hasNext()) {
                    String[] split = readFileByLine.next().split("|");
                    System.out.println(split[0]); // returns 2

  logBean.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.parse(split[0],
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") // java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
            ));
                    logBean.setIp_address(split[1]);
                    logBean.setRequest(split[2]);
                    logBean.setStatus(split[3]);
                    logBean.setUserAgent(split[4]);
                }

                return logBean;

    I want to use jpa here to do logBeanRepository.save(logbean)
    in a continuous manner
```

when i run this i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2' could not be parsed at index 0
```

so i debugged by using system.out and saw that it just reads 2 out of the whole date , what am i doing wrong?
and i would like it to continuously read and store in db

After changing the split to

```
    String[] split = readFileByLine.next().split("\\|");
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-01-01' could not be parsed at index 10
```

so now it reads at least half of the date but still not complete 
what can i do  ?

Comment: your split[0] text is not a right pattern datetime string, it should be like this pattern: 2011-12-03T10:15:30

Comment: you mean @Liuguanghua  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")  ? i tried that but thesame result i will update my question to include that

Comment: Oh well I missed that pipe completely.

Comment: well yes i am reading from a file as you see i posted part of the file

Comment: @BackSlash this question is different from that

Comment: @valik It isn't. You get `2` instead of the full date because you are splitting the wrong way. The duplicate question has the answer on how to split correctly. Use that and the `DateTimeParser`, and your program will work.

Comment: i just updated my question you will see that i looked at the linked you shared and used \\| regex to split and i got 2017-01-01 but not the whole date

Comment: @BackSlash please check my question again you will see that it doesnt solve it

Comment: @valik That's because you are using `.next()`, which reads until the first blank space. Use `.nextLine()` instead.

Comment: yes that solves the first problem thanks but how can it do it continuously for all the strings in the file

Comment: @BackSlash do you have an idea?  thank you

Comment: @valik Did you try with `nextLine()`? It should work for all lines.

Comment: i was thinking nested while ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a specific formatter:

```
logBean.setDateTime(
    LocalDateTime.parse(
        split[0],
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") // java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
    )
);
```

Comment: I did that then ran my main method to get date and it still shows thesame answer DateTimeParseException Text 2 could not be pared

Comment: @valik Then you are not parsing one of the dates you posted. Check the [demo](https://ideone.com/38kzzB), it works with the provided input.

Comment: yes probably my issue is how to read the file and split them  by pipe and also get them using setter method